# How to return multiple response in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to return the same response after the loop ends but I couldn't able to find a approach to implement it.

Here, What I have tried and error which I get local variable 'TaskId' referenced before assignment

views.py:

```
def GetCurrentRunningActivity(UserID):

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivity] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor_set = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in result_set:  
            
                TaskId=row[0]
                Number=row[1]
                Opened=row[2]
                Contacttype=row[3]
                Category1=row[4]
                State=row[5]
                Assignmentgroup=row[6]
                CountryLocation=row[7]
                Openedfor=row[8]
                Employeenumber=row[9]
                Shortdescription=row[10]
                Internaldescription=row[11]
                Additionalcomments=row[12]
                TaskName = row[1]
                print("Number", Number)
 
                return Response({ "TaskId": TaskId, "Number":Number,"Opened":Opened, "Contacttype":Contacttype,
         "Category1":Category1, "State":State, "Assignmentgroup":Assignmentgroup, "CountryLocation":CountryLocation,
         "Openedfor":Openedfor, "Employeenumber":Employeenumber , "Shortdescription":Shortdescription,
         "Internaldescription":Internaldescription, "Additionalcomments":Additionalcomments,"TaskName":TaskName},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
     
       return Response({ "TaskId": TaskId, "Number":Number,"Opened":Opened, "Contacttype":Contacttype,
     "Category1":Category1, "State":State, "Assignmentgroup":Assignmentgroup, "CountryLocation":CountryLocation,
     "Openedfor":Openedfor, "Employeenumber":Employeenumber , "Shortdescription":Shortdescription,
     "Internaldescription":Internaldescription, "Additionalcomments":Additionalcomments,"TaskName":TaskName},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with your looping logic here: you are trying to "return" every time at loops end. Instead you should collect data to a list and then return Response just once like this:

```
def GetCurrentRunningActivity(UserID):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivity] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor_set = cursor.fetchall()
    data = []
    for row in result_set:
        TaskId=row[0]
        Number=row[1]
        Opened=row[2]
        Contacttype=row[3]
        Category1=row[4]
        State=row[5]
        Assignmentgroup=row[6]
        CountryLocation=row[7]
        Openedfor=row[8]
        Employeenumber=row[9]
        Shortdescription=row[10]
        Internaldescription=row[11]
        Additionalcomments=row[12]
        TaskName = row[1]
        print("Number", Number)
        data.append({"TaskId": TaskId, "Number":Number,"Opened":Opened,
            "Contacttype":Contacttype, "Category1":Category1, "State":State,
            "Assignmentgroup":Assignmentgroup, "CountryLocation":CountryLocation,
            "Openedfor":Openedfor, "Employeenumber":Employeenumber ,
            "Shortdescription":Shortdescription, 
            "Internaldescription":Internaldescription,
            "Additionalcomments":Additionalcomments,"TaskName":TaskName
        })
    return Response({"data": data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And, please, dont forget to follow PEP8